# Implementation of scipy.signal.butter and scipy.signal.sosfilt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, scipy, phonegap

I want to call a Python method in my Cordova application. Is there a way to integrate a Python script with a Cordova application as I could not find the equivalent implementation of the same method in other languages like JavaScript except Python that I could integrate with the application?

The methods which I want to implement in JavaScript are `scipy.signal.butter` and `scipy.signal.sosfilt` which are the inbuilt methods of SciPy in Python.

Is there a way to implement these methods in JavaScript or is there a way to integrate a Python script in a Cordova application?
Any suggestion over it is greatly appreciated.